# Computing Romberg integration using java

Tags: java, math, numerical-methods

How would approximate the following integral using Romberg Integration,

```
min:1, max:1.6, 
integral (2x)/((x^2)-4)
```

Also computing the Romberg Table until `|R_n-1,n-1 - R_n,n| < 10^-8`.

Comment: If this is homework you should use the homework tag, most people are reluctant to do other people's assignments

Comment: There is a wiki page on Romberg's method that contains a full working C implementation.

Comment: Since there's a java tag, I'd say that a Java implementation might be a better idea.

Answer (score 2):

It always helps to know the answer before you start.  Here's the indefinite integral:

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+%282x%29%2F%28%28x%5E2%29-4%29

And here's the definite integral using your limits:

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+%282x%29%2F%28%28x%5E2%29-4%29+from+x%3D1+to+1.6

Numerical integration usually means evaluating your function at a number of points and combining results in the manner prescribed by your integration scheme.

If [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romberg%27s_method) is the formula for Romberg integration, what's the difficulty?

Google could have found you a Java implementation:

http://alpcentauri.info/nmjava6.htm